# Excel returns a fault code for my module code in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I'm trying to streamline our workflow in Excel by creating a "button" that automatically creates a PDF of the selected print area.

I've used a concat formula for the text in F3 (to differentiate the files so that they won't overwrite each other).

When pressing the button, I get `Run-time error'-2147024773(8007007b)': Document not saved` in the last lines of code in the module.

Could anyone assist me with this?

This is the code:

```
Sub CreatePDF()
'
'Create PDF

    'Variables
    Dim newfilename As String
    
    'Make a filename
    newfilename = "C:\Users\TRL\Skrivebord" & _
        ActiveSheet.Range("F3").Value & ".pdf"
        
    'Make the PDF
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=x1TypePDF, _
    Filename:=newfilename, _
    Quality:=x1QualityStandard, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
    
End Sub
```

I'm getting a fault from "Make the PDF" through "End Sub".

Noted: The path where the file is saved is on a one-drive location, but I've changed the code above for "security-reasons". If this is indeed the root of the problem I'll would have to get a green light from the upper-ups to add this. But again, I'm not getting any problems with that specific line of code.

Comment: The error code is this: "Run-time error'-2147024773(8007007b)': Document not saved

Comment: Have you checked `newfilename`? I assume you miss the backslash between the path and the filename (that you read from a cell). It could also be that the content of the cell doesn't hold a valid file name. And `x1TypePDF` is wrong, it's `xlTypePDF` - use Option Explicit to see such errors.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas!

Where would I put the backlash you recommended? As stated above I've changed the file path in my question.

Comment: Either type `Skrivebord\" & _ ` or `Skrivebord" & "\" & _`. Try changing the other x1 to xl as well since Quality also doesn't have `x1QualityStandard` but `xlQualityStandard`

Comment: for example `"C:\Users\TRL\Skrivebord\"`

Comment: Thanks, Notus_Panda!

I've been able to troubleshoot the problem at It seems to be an issue with the "F3" value as this is a concat formula that would "spit out" a unique name for each file. 

Is is possible to add the concat code directly in to VBA?

The code in F3 is: =CONCAT(C2;" - ";C3;" ";C4;"|";TEXT(C5;"DD.MM.ÅÅ"))

Comment: *Is is possible to add the concat code directly in to VBA?* Yes, it is. You may use [Evaluate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) or concatenate in code with operator ampersand `&`

Comment: When you are saving to OneDrive you need to use a URL and ensure that you have sync settings correctly set - I can't remember the exact details just now but that might help you with your research

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns So I would need to add it like this?: newFilename = "C:\Users\Skrivebord\" & _ CONCAT(C2;" - ";C3;" ";C4;"|";TEXT(C5;"DD.MM.ÅÅ")) & ".pdf

Comment: More something like `Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range("C2")` with `newFileName = "C:\Users\Skrivebord\" & _  rng.Value & "-" & rng.Offset(1).Value & " " & rng.Offset(2) & "|" & Format(rng.Offset(3).Value,"dd.mm.yy") & ".pdf"` (though the date format will still use dd/mm/yy but that might just be my local settings

Comment: After adding the above code, I now get that "Document not saved".

Any other changes needed in code below? @Notus_Panda?

Sorry for the incompetence!

Comment: Have you changed the x1 to xl by now?